# Find First Occurrence of Substring Before Index

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, find, substring

Is there an analogy to `myStr.find(subStr, startInd)` in order to get the index of the first occurrence of `subStr` **before** my `startInd`. Like taking step -1 instead of 1 from `startInd`?

**Edit**

Here an example:

```
myStr = "(I am a (cool) str)"

startInd = 9  # print(myStr[startInd]) -> "c"

print(myStr.find(")", startInd))  # -> 13
print(myStr.findBefore("(", startInd))  # -> 8
```

**Edit II**

The following code solves my problem but it is not really convenient. Wanted to ask if there is a simple method to fullfill that task

```
startInd = 9

myStr = "(I am a (cool) str)"

print(myStr.find(")", startInd))  # -> 13
print(len(myStr[::-1]) - myStr[::-1].find("(", len(myStr[::-1]) - startInd - 1) - 1)  # -> 8
```

Comment: Are you just looking for [`rfind`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind)?

Comment: @abarnert no not quite. I have added an example to my question to make it more clear what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

[`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) takes an optional `end` parameter:

> **str.find(sub[, start[, end]])**
>
> Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found within the slice s[start:end]. Optional arguments start and end are
>   interpreted as in slice notation.

So, if you want `subStr` to *end* before `endIndex`, you can use `myStr.find(subStr, 0, endIndex)`:

```
>>> 'hello world'.find('ello', 0, 5)
1
>>> 'hello world'.find('ello', 0, 4)  # "ello" ends at index 5, so it's not found
-1
>>> 'hello world'[0:4]
'hell'
```

If you want `subStr` to *start* anywhere before `endIndex`, you have to use `myStr.find(subStr, 0, endIndex + len(subStr))` instead:

```
>>> 'hello world'.find('ello', 0, 1 + len('ello'))
1
>>> 'hello world'.find('ello', 0, 0 + len('ello'))  # it starts at index 1, so it's not found
-1
```